# DAX Time Intelligence Functions - Is there a way to get the underlying DAX code?

Tags: dax

Many, or perhaps all, DAX time intelligence functions are actually expanded to more complex DAX code when called. Is there anyway to determine exactly what this code is for each function? This would be very helpful to know if I ever have to create a Date table that isn't at the day granularity and I need to rewrite a time intelligence function to handle a date table at say the month granularity.

Answer (score 0):

It's listed on https://dax.guide for each of the time intelligence functions.

For example, https://dax.guide/totalmtd.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm aware of DAX guide. However, not all time intelligence functions contain this information. For example, PARALLELPERIOD does not.